# why svn remove some url failed

Tags: svn

I want to remove a svn url but failed

```
svn rm --force https://svn.int.foobar.com/svn/server/admin/coupon -m 'delete it'
svn: E175013: Access to '/svn/server/!svn/txr/83053-1t88/admin/coupon' forbidden
```

Why is so? and how to remove it?

But if create some new path it could be deleted successfully

```
svn mkdir https://svn.int.foobar.com/svn/server/admin/test -m 'create'
Committing transaction...
Committed revision 83054.
svn rm https://svn.int.foobar.com/svn/server/admin/test -m 'delete'
Committing transaction...
Committed revision 83055.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have Write access to the path you plan removing. That's why you get "Access Forbidden" error.

Comment: but it was created by me before